# Threaded function cant recall itself ( python 2.7 )

Tags: python, multithreading

in my kivy app, I have a threaded function that constantly checks for updates on the name ( client ) list, which stores the names of currently connected clients ( from my sockets part of the program ) the thing is when the function ends I have it call itself to repeat the checking process. but it won't work:

```
def check_names(self):
    for name in names:
        if name not in self.namelist.adapter.data:
            self.namelist.adapter.data.extend([name])
    print "checked names"
    time.sleep(2)
    self.check_names()

print "\nstarting name-checking process"
check_names_thread = threading.Thread(target=check_names)
check_names_thread.start()
```

I get this error :

```
   File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
 TypeError: check_names() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

and when I add an argument, like this :

```
check_names_thread = threading.Thread(target=check_names, args=" ")
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
     self.run()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
   File "D:/04 - Media/Python Projects/4 - Networking/Send_Variable_Test/Server.py", line 136, in check_names
     self.check_names()
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'check_names'
```

how do I fix this?

edit: 
this is the full picture:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):

    def check_names(self):
        for name in names:
            if name not in self.namelist.adapter.data:
                self.namelist.adapter.data.extend([name])
        print "checked names"
        time.sleep(2)
        self.check_names()

    print "\nstarting name-checking process"
    check_names_thread = threading.Thread(target=check_names, args=" ")
    check_names_thread.start()
```

Comment: Remove `self` you're not in a class

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `self` as a parameter to the function? That's for methods on class instances, this is not a method. Remove that argument and just use `check_names()` to call it.

Comment: I have (self) as a parameter because the function exists within a class ( a Screen class for my kivy app )

Comment: Well you need to show it in context then, partial code isn't helpful. Where is the calling code (the last three lines) in relation to that class?

Comment: Well, that makes no sense. Those three lines are at class level and are called at definition time. There is no reason for any of that to be within a class.

Comment: how do i fix it then

Comment: Remove the class, remove the `self`.

Comment: ok its working now, but its not adding anything to the listview, why is this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a plain function, then your loop should not involve recursion:

```
def check_names():
    while True:
        for name in names:
            if name not in self.namelist.adapter.data:
                self.namelist.adapter.data.extend([name])
        print "checked names"
        time.sleep(2)
```

But now you have the problem of how to exit this function ;-)

Comment: that's not a problem, but the function is not adding anything to the listview, why is this?

Comment: What is a `listview`?

Comment: it's a kivy widget. if you don't have any experience with kivy, ignore this question.